# How to let pwsh (powershell 7) use windows terminal color scheme?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I have installed powershell 7, basically `pwsh.exe`.

When I launch powershell 7 inside **Windows Terminal** App, it uses **Windows Terminal** Color Theme profile. But when I launch `pwsh.exe` separately, it doesn't use the color theme, instead it's using the default black background color theme.

How can I let `pwsh.exe` use **Windows Terminal**'s color theme when launching it separately? Thanks a lot.

Comment: i don't think you can. when running ps7 directly, it appears to use the system conhost ... the same thing that ps5.1 and cmd.exe use. you likely would need to use a shortcut to allow a custom color setup OR use the PSReadline stuff to define & load a custom color scheme.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks a lot for the comment. If it's not possible, should I delete this question?

Comment: you are most welcome [*grin*] ... and please _do not_ delete the Question. it is a reasonable Question and others may have the same interest ... plus, i have been wrong many times - so you may get a usable Answer in a while.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do with `pwsh.exe` is right-clicking where you move the window and open Preferences. There you can change Font, Layout, Screen Colors, and Terminal colors. As for using the `.json` files like in Windows Terminal: does not seem possible (as from other comments)